# How to handle async calls by using Flutter Riverpod StateNotifier

Tags: flutter, architecture, flutter-riverpod

Which of the following ways is the proper approach to handle async calls using Riverpod in Flutter? Should I worry about the getStringResult asynchronous call when the controller is being disposed as I do in approach B? Or shouldn't worry about the async call, can I use the simple approach A?

Approach 'A'

```
class Controller extends StateNotifier<String> {
    final Repository repository;
    
    Controller(this.repository):super(null);
    
    startAsyncJob() async {
        state = await repository.getStringResult()
    }
}
```

Approach 'B' by using the StreamSubscription

```
class Controller extends StateNotifier<String> {
    final Repository repository;
    StreamSubsciption? sub;

    Controller(this.repository):super(null);
    
    startAsyncJob {
        sub?.cancel();
        sub = repository.getStringResult().asStream().listen(event) {
            state = event;
        });
    }

    @override
    dispose() {
        sub?.cancel()
        super.dispose()
    }
}
```

I am using  Approach 'B' in my controllers but it seems overkill to me. Did I overthink the problem? Will the async calls be disposed automatically when the controller does dispose?

Comment: I'd stop using any of the legacy riverpod providers and concentrate on AsyncNotifier, Notifier, and their provider counterparts.  Then, your dispose could be put inside your build, and it'd make a lot more sense.  And generating family providers is far more fun!

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Please could you describe it more deeply? https://riverpod.dev/docs/providers/state_notifier_provider
Isn't StateNotifier the recommended way to go?

Comment: As I said, the legacy providers are still there and supported, but the new stuff with [Async]Notifier[Provider] is a functional superset of all of the old stuff, except for StreamProvider (and I understand StreamNotifier[Provider] is on the way).

Comment: Thank you Randal, I am going to read the documentation to understand the new stuff!